# How to put json response in a string

Tags: java, android, json

I have a `json` like this :

```
{
 "p": {
"Name": "216",
"Serial": "b216",
"IsDeactive": false,
"PicLink": "data/upload/pic.jpg",
"Description": "ABC"
      }
}
```

Now i want to put variables from the json to variables in android.
for example i want to put "Name" from json response to String name in android.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray array = jObject.getJSONArray("p");
String name= jObject.getString("Name");
```

But it's giving me nothing!!
how can i fix this?

Comment: `p` is not an array. And when you try to get `name`, you are referring to the top level object again(and not using the array you just tried to create), and that has no property called `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject p = jObject.getJSONObject("p");
String name= p.getString("Name");
```